# Underlining User Input in C

Tags: c

Here is a sample run of this program, assuming that the executable file is called match and hit. This run illustrates a situation where the human player wins the game. User input is 
bolded.

> /home/userXYZ/ECE15/Lab3> match_and_hit
>  
>    Welcome to the MATCH and HIT game
>   The computer has selected a 4-digit number.
>   Try to deduce it in 12 rounds of queries.
>
> Round #1
>   Please enter your query (4 digits): **5341** <---(this number should be underlined)

.......

I can't figure out how to underline the user input. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a CLI (Command Line Interface) application?

Comment: does your terminal support underlined text? or do you want `-` characters on the next row?

Comment: i dono anything about CLI application. my professor asked me to make the user input underline

Comment: Does your professor know curses?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your terminal supports ANSI escape sequences, you can use this:

```
#define ANSI_UNDERLINED_PRE  "\033[4m"
#define ANSI_UNDERLINED_POST "\033[0m"

printf(ANSI_UNDERLINED_PRE "underlined" ANSI_UNDERLINED_POST "\n");
```

Comment: where should i write the printf statement? right after scanning the user input or what?

Comment: @NaregRostami you can use something like this: `printf("Please enter your query (4 digits): "); printf(ANSI_UNDERLINED_PRE); scanf("%d", bla); printf(ANSI_UNDERLINED_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

With a CLI Application, you cannot, that would be dependent on the actual terminal that is calling your application.

Comment: i have to come up with a function that does the underline for user input?/

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal supports it:

```
printf("\x1b[04mUnderlined\x1b[24mUnderlineOff");
```